# Passing alias template to base class of a template it depends on

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Consider the following code, that defines an alias template to be passed as an template template parameter:

```
template<template<class T> class SomeFoo>
class Base {};

template<class T, class Bar>
class Foo {};

class Bar;

template<class T>
using BarFoo = Foo<T, Bar>;

class Bar : public Base<BarFoo> {};
```

This works as expected. However, if `Bar` itself is a template, this solution is not possible, as the alias template depends on the concrete instantiation of `Bar`. Defining the alias template inside of `Bar` doesn't help either, as it is not yet available when the base class is given. As it seems not to be possible to define the alias template "on the fly" in the parameter list, the only work around I could come up with is to pass `Bar` to `Base` and define the alias template there:

```
template<template<class T, class Derived> class SomeFooTL, class Derived>
class Base
{
    template<class T>
    using SomeFoo = SomeFooTL<T, Derived>;
};

template<class T, class Bar>
class Foo {};

template<class S>
class Bar : public Base<Foo, Bar<S>> {};
```

This is, however, very unsatisfying, as there could be (and are) other `Foo`'s that do not depend on anything but `T` and now are forced to take an unnecessary second template parameter.

Does anyone know a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Not sure I get it, but can't you pass a class in which you have a template<...> using type = ...; instead of passing a template?

Comment: @lorro I think I see what you're getting at, I have to think that through... (BTW What's unclear about the question? Maybe I can rephrase it.) EDIT: Yeah, I think that should work! Make it a proper answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you need an helper, and using a not obvious syntax:

```
template<template<class> class>
class Base {};

template<class, class>
class Foo {};

template <typename> class Bar;

template <typename S> struct UsingHelper {
    template <typename T>
    using BarFoo = Foo<T, Bar<S>>;
};

template <typename S>
class Bar : public Base<UsingHelper<S>::template BarFoo> {};
```

`template` is needed in `UsingHelper<S>::template BarFoo` as it is a dependent context, and it would be "interpreted" as value instead without. (it is similar to `typename my_class<T>::type`, but `BarFoo` is a template, not a type.)

Comment: This solves it very nicely! It's even cleaner than passing the template template parameter inside helper class as it doesn't pollute the base class. You could make it even shorter by having the UsingHelper take Bar directly as a template paramter and thus get rid of the forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
template<template<class T> class SomeFoo>
class Base {};
```

You might want:

```
template<class SomeFooT>
class Base {};
```

And use `SomeFooT::type<T>` as a template:

```
struct BarFooT {
    template<typename T>
    using type = ...;
};
```

Then you can predeclare `struct BarFooT;`.

Comment: Can you be more specific how forward declaring BarFooT helps? (Or am I missing something here?)